# custom attribute save is not working during regsitration

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute, magento2.2.6

I have created custom attribute, and i'm displaying those attribute in registration page. When user clicks on create an account i get values for custom attribute from post value. But when i tried to save it to custom attribute its not saving i checked data in customer_entity_varchar and customer_entity_tex tables.
Here is my code

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }    

        $this->session->regenerateId();

        try {
            $address = $this->extractAddress();

            $addresses[] = $address === null ? [] : $billingAddress;

            $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
            $customer->setAddresses($addresses);
            $attribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('title');
            if($attribute) {
                $attribute->setValue($this->getRequest()->getParam('title'));
            }
            $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
            $confirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation');
            $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeAuthUrl();

            $this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);

            $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);
            $customer->setData('title', $this->getRequest()->getParam('title'));
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
                $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
            }

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'customer_register_success',
                ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
            );

            $confirmationStatus = $this->accountManagement->getConfirmationStatus($customer->getId());
            if ($confirmationStatus === AccountManagementInterface::ACCOUNT_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED) {
                $email = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail());
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __(
                        'You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the confirmation link or <a href="%1">click here</a> for a new link.',
                        $email
                    )
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/index', ['_secure' => true]);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($url));
            } else {
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);              
            }
            if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                $metadata->setPath('/');
                $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
            }

            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (StateException $e) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $message = __(
                'There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%1">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.',
                $url
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($error->getMessage()));
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
        }

        $this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

code to create custom attribute for customer

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, 
ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $setup->startSetup();

    // Adding the 'is active' attribute
    $attributesInfo = [
        self::CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE =>
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Account is Active',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'backend' => Boolean::class,
                'position' => 28,
                'required' => false,
                'adminhtml_only' => true,
                'default' => true,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0
            ],

            self::TITLE =>[
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Title',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system'       => 0,
                'required'     => false,
                'global'       => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0
            ],

            self::ACCOUNT_MANAGER =>[
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Account Manager',
                'input'        => 'select',
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system'       => 0,
                'required'     => false,
                'global'       => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0
            ]

    ];

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }

    $newAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE);
    $newAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit'],
    ]);

    $newAttribute->save();

    $newAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::TITLE);
    $newAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'],
    ]);

    $newAttribute->save();

    $newAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::ACCOUNT_MANAGER);
    $newAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit'],
    ]);

    $newAttribute->save();
```

Comment: Please share your code how you create custom attribute

Comment: did you try this code? $customer->setCustomAttribute('title',$this->getRequest()->getParam('title'));

Comment: yes i tried its not working.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma please check my post i have updated with code to create custom attribute for customer.